# Linked List- NULL pointer check?

Tags: c, pointers, allocation

In this code snippet for adding to a Linked List, what is if (List==NULL) doing?  I tried to throw some inputs at it to see if I could engage that statement with no luck. What type of input would work?

```
main()
{
    struct Node *List;
    List = NULL;

    append (&List, 5);
}



void append(struct Node **List, int num)
{
    if (List == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }


    if (*List == NULL)
    {
        *List = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        (*List)->data = num;
        (*List)->next = NULL;

    }
   //some additional cases edited out for brevity
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear *List == NULL checks for empty head, but what does List ==NULL do?

Comment: This is how you engage, other than passing NULL directly: `struct Node **a = NULL;append(a, 5);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for whatever reason you (or the user of your library) call `append(NULL,42);` then, thanks to the `if(List == NULL)` check, your program won't crash. Otherwise (if you remove the `if(List == NULL)` check) it is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and practically [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) would happen. That check is an instance of [defensive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming).

In principle it looks like `append` is intended to be called as `append(&somevar, someint)` but this is not documented, so adding the extract check (which is *extremely cheap* at runtime!) is worthwhile.

Comment: ...ah that was quite simple. I feel a little stupid now... I might have been over thinking it I guess, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass NULL as the List pointer the program will crash when you dereference it in:

```
if (*List == NULL)
```

So you must check that that function wasn't called with NULL as the parameter